# How To Break A Group of Words In A Line Into 5 lines of words

Tags: javascript, html, string

The string example is like this
"This is a long sentence that I need to break into 5 lines but no matter how hard I try I cannot seem to get it to work on my website I need help thank you"

## Result should be:

1 Row - Max 50 Characters per Row

"This is a long sentence that I need to break"

2 Row - Max 50 Characters Per Row

"into 5 lines but no matter how hard I try I"

3 Row - Max 50 Characters Per Row

"cannot seem to get it to work on website I"

4 Row - Max 50 Characters Per Row

"need help thank you"

5 Row - Max 50 Character but it's blank as it hit finish the string.

=============

Here is the script I have now

```
var string = "spand span spand span";
var arr = string.split(" ");
var unique = [];
var arrcount = [];
$.each(arr, function (index,word) {
    if ($.inArray(word, unique) === -1) 
        unique.push(word);
        arrcount.push(word.split(" ").length);
});
alert(unique+arrcount);
```

======
I cannot seem to figure how to be able to count the total string of words and break the string after it hits 50 characters by words only and do not want to break the words by character.

I found what I was looking for :)

```
function splitLine(st,n) 
{var b = ''; var s = st;while (s.length > n) {var c = s.substring(0,n);var d = c.lastIndexOf(' ');var e =c.lastIndexOf('\n');if (e != -1) d = e; if (d == -1) d = n; b +=       c.substring(0,d) + '\n';s = s.substring(d+1);}return b+s;}

var myText="This is a long sentence that I need to break into 5 lines but no matter how hard I try I cannot seem to get it to work on my website I need help thank you";                 

var myText40 = splitLine(myText,50);
var myHTML = myText40.replace(/\n/g,'<br \/><br \/>');
```

Comment: your code does not match what you are asking.  Please add the code you tried for this particular situation.

Comment: Your script is for finding unique words, it has nothing to do with limiting the number of characters on a line. Did you copy the wrong code?

Comment: You can use `word.length` to get the number of characters in the word. Use a variable to keep a running total of the word lengths (don't forget to include the space between words), and when it goes above 50 save the row and start a new one.

Comment: Why wouldn't the first piece be *This is a long sentence that I need to break into*? "into" puts it at 49 characters

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Maybe he counted the quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will split the string into lines of at most 50 characters each. If you actually want 5 lines, you should use a smaller limit -- you could use `maxlen = string.length/5` to get an even spread.

```
var rows = [];
var maxlen = 50;
var arr = string.split(" ");
var currow = arr[0];
var rowlen = currow.length;
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var word = arr[i];
    rowlen += word.length + 1;
    if (rowlen <= maxlen) {
        currow += " " + word;
    } else {
        rows.push(currow);
        currow = word;
        rowlen = word.length;
    }
}
rows.push(currow);
```

Given your input string, it returns:

```
["This is a long sentence that I need to break into",  // 49 characters
 "5 lines but no matter how hard I try I cannot seem", // 50 characters
 "to get it to work on my website I need help thank",  // 49 characters
 "you"]                                                // 3 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="dv">This is a long sentence that I need to break into 5 lines but no matter how hard I try I cannot seem to get it to work on my website I need help thank you</div>


var text = $("#dv").html();
var newtext = text.match(/.{1,44}/g).join("<br/>");
$("#dv").html(newtext);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9cc2mdLy/)**

Note I added the `<br/>` after **44** words to achieve the text you mentioned in questioned. Having them **50** will add `<br/>` at different position. I guess you didn't count `spaces`.

Comment: This will split lines in the middle of words.

Comment: the OP has mentioned in the question Max 50 **characters** per row.

Answer (score -1):

Found what I was looking for thanks everyone for your help

```
function splitLine(st,n) 
{var b = ''; var s = st;while (s.length > n) {var c = s.substring(0,n);var d = c.lastIndexOf(' ');var e =c.lastIndexOf('\n');if (e != -1) d = e; if (d == -1) d = n; b +=       c.substring(0,d) + '\n';s = s.substring(d+1);}return b+s;}

var myText="This is a long sentence that I need to break into 5 lines but no matter how hard I try I cannot seem to get it to work on my website I need help thank you";                 

var myText40 = splitLine(myText,50);
var myHTML = myText40.replace(/\n/g,'<br \/><br \/>');
```

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, you are more than welcome to.  However, your question needs to be reworded to actually make sense and have a good example of the code you tried to attempt the problem you proposed.  You can't just paste some random code and hope to get an answer.